# Does not contain a definition for 'RootVisual' in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

In this code "RootVisual" is Not Existing in WP8.1

```
(Application.Current.RootVisual as 
    PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/FeedBackMessageBox.xaml", 
    UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Application.RootVisual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.application.rootvisual%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is only for Silverlight apps. For a Windows Phone Runtime app use Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Content:

```
(Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(FeedBackMessageBox),args);
```

See [Quickstart: Navigating between pages (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx) for more details on navigation in Windows Runtime apps.